# Ember: Secureness in model-responses with private data

Tags: ember.js, database-design, ember-data

If writing an ember application using ember-data with an Backend for persistence, how can I handle sensitive data?

Lets thing about the following szenario:

**"As a user I want to log into my app"**
=> *the client (ember-data) will hold an **instance of User** with all neccessary informations. Their are also some fields included which are very **private** like the Facebook-UID for example or something else.*

**"A a user I want to manage a list of my friends"** => *Okay, it seems like on some routes, the client have to fetch other user-records from the database to resolve for example the names of the people who are related as id's in the 'myFriends'-field of the current user object*

**The model for User**

```
name: DS.attr('String'),
myFriends: DS.hasMany('User')
```

So basically the problem is that some Data-Records has references to other Data-Records from the same model but some of the fields in the records are not public and therefore shouldn't be requestable. But Ember-Data will allways request the whole model and even when im writing my backend in the way of sending back ony reduced data-records I guess that ember-data wont like that when some of the fields are marked as "undefinied", right?

Comment: No, only id is required. Other fields may be omitted in server's response.

Answer (score 1):

You can leave that data out, set it to null or some arbitrary value. But I would recommend to use a `UserPrivate` model class that contains all of the non-public information. That way, it's more obvious what's happening (read: maintenance friendly) and the server may even respond to a private `UserPrivate` model of another User with HTTP status code 403 (Forbidden).